# How to get all children from parent path in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

My json data looks like bellow.

```
{
    "_id" : "Assets",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : null
}


{
    "_id" : "Bank",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,"
}


{
    "_id" : "Cash",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,"
}


{
    "_id" : "NRI",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,"
}


{
    "_id" : "Local",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,"
}


{
    "_id" : "SBI",
    "Act_Type" : false,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,Local,"
}


{
    "_id" : "Canara",
    "Act_Type" : false,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,Local,"
}


{
    "_id" : "ICICI",
    "Act_Type" : false,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,NRI,"
}


{
    "_id" : "HDFC",
    "Act_Type" : false,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,NRI,"
}
```

I'm using Model Tree Structures with Materialized Paths when trying to retrieve data from parent path not getting all values Ex: my path is ",Assets," , i'm getting only

```
{
    "_id" : "Bank",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,"
}
```

but I need

```
{
    "_id" : "Bank",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,"
}


{
    "_id" : "Cash",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,"
}


{
    "_id" : "NRI",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,"
}


{
    "_id" : "Local",
    "Act_Type" : true,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,"
}


{
    "_id" : "SBI",
    "Act_Type" : false,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,Local,"
}


{
    "_id" : "Canara",
    "Act_Type" : false,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,Local,"
}


{
    "_id" : "ICICI",
    "Act_Type" : false,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,NRI,"
}


{
    "_id" : "HDFC",
    "Act_Type" : false,
    "Path" : ",Assets,Bank,NRI,"
}
```

plz help me how to query using java....

Comment: show some code, how do you retrieve the collection

Comment: BasicDBObject findQuery = new BasicDBObject();
findQuery.put("_id", _id);
findQuery.put("Path", path);
DBCursor get_document = example.find(findQuery);
 System.out.println("DOC "+get_document);
 while(get_document.hasNext())                                  {
DBObject doc = get_document.next();      System.out.println(doc);                                        }

Comment: Try not setting the _id

Comment: i tried but i'm getting same..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" );
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("testCollection");
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Path", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
try {
 while(cursor.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(cursor.next());
 }
} finally {
 cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Cursor id=0, ns=Example.Example, query={ ",Assets," : { "$exists" : true}}, numIterated=0, readPreference=primary

Comment: try find(), without arguments

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would need to use [regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) for this because what you have for `Path` is a `String` and not an `Array`

Try this:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Path", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "*Asset*"));
```